# pointers as attributes in extended types cython

Tags: python, c, pointers, cython

I'm a newbie to cython with a bit of knowledge in C and some python experience. Currently I'm trying to learn about Extended Types, but I can not understand what happens with pointers values in the following example (code below the explanation).

As an exercise, I'm implementing a dummy solver. The problem is represented by two numbers 'a' and 'b' and the solution by 's', where s = a*b.

I defined two corresponding C structures, `problem` and `solution`. The problem structure has two int members, 'a' and 'b'; the solution structure has one member 's'. There is one function to initialize the problem structure, `init_problem(problem *p,int a, int b)`. Also, there is one function that take pointers to the structs and returns a solution, `solution solve(problem *p)`. Finally, two other functions print the values (`void dump_problem(problem *p)`and `void dump_solution(solution *s)`). All of this using `cdef` declarations.

Next I used three ways to expose the C code to python: a `def` function `do_things(int a,int b)` which wraps the C functions, and two `cdef class`, one using structs as attributes and the other one using pointers to structs as attributes (`Solver_s` and `Solver_p`, respectively), including wraping methods to print problem and solutions. Solver_s class work as expected; however, when using Solver_p, pointers seems not to be initialized, returning incorrect values (see test_pointers and output sections).

I guess I missing a fine point about pointers and their scope, but I can not understand what is going on. Any help to get this is greatly appreciated. I'm using python 3.5.3 and cython 0.25.2 in OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

P.S: First time asking in SO, so if I'm not being clear I'll glad to clarify!

pointers.pyx

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf

cdef struct problem:
    int a
    int b

cdef struct solution:
    int s

cdef void init_problem(problem *p,int a, int b):
    p.a = a
    p.b = b

cdef solution solve(problem *p):
    cdef solution s
    s.s = p.a * p.b
    return(s)

cdef void dump_problem(problem *p):
    printf("Problem dump: a = %d,b = %d\n",p.a,p.b)

cdef void dump_solution(solution *s):
    printf("Solution dump: s= %d\n",s.s)

def do_things(int a,int b):
    cdef problem p
    init_problem(&p,a,b)
    cdef solution s = solve(&p)
    dump_problem(&p)
    dump_solution(&s)

cdef class Solver_s: #Structs as attributes of Solver
    cdef problem p
    cdef solution s
    def __cinit__(self,int a,int b):
        print("\tInside Solver_s __cinit__")
        init_problem(&self.p,a,b)
        dump_problem(&self.p)
        self.s = solve(&self.p)
        dump_solution(&self.s)
        print("\tGetting out of Solver_s __cinit__")

    def show_problem(self):
        dump_problem(&self.p)

    def show_solution(self):
        dump_solution(&self.s)

cdef class Solver_p: #Pointers to structs as attributes
    cdef problem *pptr
    cdef solution *sptr

    def __cinit__(self,int a, int b):
        print("\tInside Solver_p __cinit__")
        cdef problem p
        self.pptr = &p
        cdef solution s
        self.sptr = &s
        init_problem(self.pptr,a,b)
        dump_problem(self.pptr) #It shows right values
        self.sptr[0] = solve(self.pptr)
        dump_solution(self.sptr) #It shows right values
        print("\tGetting out of Solver_p  __cinit__")


    def show_problem(self):
        dump_problem(self.pptr) 

    def show_solution(self):
        dump_solution(self.sptr)
```

test_pointers.py

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import pointers

print("\tSolving as a function")
pointers.do_things(2,3)

print("\tSolving as a Extended Type, structs as attributes")
sol_s = pointers.Solver_s(4,5)
print("\t###Problem definition unsing Solver_s methods###")
sol_s.show_problem()
print("\t###Solution definition using Solver_s methods###")
sol_s.show_solution()


print("\tSolving as a Extended Type, pointers to structs as attributes")
sol_p = pointers.Solver_p(6,7)
print("\t###Problem definition unsing Solver_p methods###")
print("\t###Gives weird values###")
sol_p.show_problem()
print("\t###Solution definition using Solver_p methods###")
print("\t###Gives weird values###")
sol_p.show_solution()
```

Output

```
    Solving as a function
Problem dump: a = 2,b = 3
Solution dump: s= 6
    Solving as a Extended Type, structs as attributes
    Inside Solver_s __cinit__
Problem dump: a = 4,b = 5
Solution dump: s= 20
    Getting out of Solver_s __cinit__
    ###Problem definition unsing Solver_s methods###
Problem dump: a = 4,b = 5
    ###Solution definition using Solver_s methods###
Solution dump: s= 20
    Solving as a Extended Type, pointers to structs as attributes
    Inside Solver_p __cinit__
Problem dump: a = 6,b = 7
Solution dump: s= 42
    Getting out of Solver_p  __cinit__
    ###Problem definition unsing Solver_p methods###
    ###Gives weird values###
Problem dump: a = 1,b = 0
    ###Solution definition using Solver_p methods###
    ###Gives weird values###
Solution dump: s= 185295816
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Solver_p.__cinit__`, `p` and `s` are local variables which only exist for the duration of the call to `__cinit__`. The `Solver_p` instance lasts beyond the call, and thus for most of its lifetime the pointers are to invalid data.

The solution is to allocate heap memory instead:

```
# at the top
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef class Solver_p:
    # ....
    def __cinit__(self,...):
       self.pptr = <problem*>malloc(sizeof(problem))
       self.sptr = <solution*>malloc(sizeof(solution))
       # ...
    def __dealloc__(self):
       free(self.pptr)
       free(self.sptr)
       # ...
```

You need to be careful to make sure that all the memory you allocate is appropriately freed.

---

My advice is that if you don't understand how to use pointers correctly in C then you *should not* be using them in Cython.